# Hiding legend in PrimeNG

Tags: angular, chart.js, primeng

So I want to hide my legend in my piechart because the 52 labels are taking too much space but I can't find a way to do it in primeNG.

**My Code:**

chart.component.html

```
    <p-chart type="doughnut" [data]="monthlyTeamCost"></p-chart>
```

declaration in my component.ts

```
this.monthlyTeamCost = {
                    labels: team,
                    options: {labels: {display: false}},
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            data: amount,
                            backgroundColor: colorArr,
                        }],
                    };
```

So all the data is fine just the labels should be hidden.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to bind options to an object like this :

```
<p-chart type="doughnut" [data]="monthlyTeamCost" [options]="chartOptions"></p-chart>
```

Then in you TS File :

```
this.chartOptions = {
  legend: {display: false}
}
```

Prime NG is a binding of Chart.JS (for charting part of the library), so you can found the exhaustive list of options in the Chart.JS web site : http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/

Comment: This worked after some little changes (options instead of option and legend instead of legends)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

HTML:

```
<p-chart type="horizontalBar" [data]="data" [options]="options"></p-chart>
```

In your TS file:

```
options = {
  legend: {display: false}  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
options: {
   plugins: {
     legend: {display: false},
   }
}
```

This is the solution.